# Problems with spaces in SPE Sitecore queries

Tags: powershell-extensions, sitecore-query

I am using Sitecore 9.0 and SXA 1.8 and scaffolded a new tenant and site named `New Tenant` and `New Site`. When executing the following query using SPE I get not results:

```
Get-Item -Path master:// -Query "/sitecore/content/New tenant/New site//*"
```

I tried to use `#` characters to escape the space, but with no luck:

```
Get-Item -Path master:// -Query "fast:/sitecore/content/#New tenant#/#New site#//*"
```

Rebuilding the link database does not help either.

When I remove the spaces from the items and the query it (immediately) works:

```
Get-Item -Path master:// -Query "/sitecore/content/tenant/*"
```

How to query in SPE for items that contain spaces?

Comment: I just tried Get-Item -Path master:// -Query "/sitecore/content/SiteName/Home/About/#News and Events#/#Press Releases#//*"  in my solution and it is working perfect for me

Comment: After waiting a while and adding spaces again it works fine, even without the `#` characters. Could it be caching?